# onfocus function in javascript without using id

Tags: javascript

I have a table and few rows, when the user enters a value in the cell, it checks for correct format and pop's up message if the value is incorrect and I want the focus to stay in the current cell. I dont have id in my input type, directly passing the value.

can anybody tell me, without using document.getElementByid().focus(), any other way to focus on the current cell.

TIA

Comment: Can you post some code, please?  It would be useful to know your HTML structure to see what's going on.

Comment: Don't trap the focus in an input. It's very user hostile and prevents people going to other parts of the document to check something before going back and fixing the error.

Answer (score 2):

If the event handler is bound to the input then you should be able to capture it with `this`. Otherwise you should be able to read the `target` property of [the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).